# _matherr does not get called in release build (C++ Builder 2007)

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++builder

I have a code with possible floating point overflows which cannot be managed by checking arguments of functions. I have to define `_matherr` and throw an exception from inside it in order to give a chance to caller to manage the problem.

There is something strange: in Debug build, _matherr is called as supposed, but not in Release. I use CodeGear C++ Builder 2007. Under MSVC 2010 the handler works fine, but I need VCL features for the whole application. Googling gives nothing but messages about `_matherr` not working in DLL (that is known from documentation).

And my question is: what could be the reason for `_matherr` to not work in Release?

```
// One of the methods with overflows.
double DoubleExponential::F(double x) const
{
    try
    {
        double y=pow(fabs(x),a);
        return 0.5 + sign(x)*G(y,1/a)/(2*G(1/a));
    }
    catch(PowExpOverflow)
    {
        return 0.5;
    }
}

// Exception.
struct PowExpOverflow {};

int _matherr (struct _exception *a){
    Application->MessageBox("Inside custom _matherr", "", MB_OK);
    if (a->type == OVERFLOW)
        if (!strcmp(a->name,"pow") ||
            !strcmp(a->name,"powl") ||
            !strcmp(a->name,"exp") ||
            !strcmp(a->name,"expl"))
        {
            throw PowExpOverflow();
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I find this a little odd. I thought all the Embarcadero tools used a control word that did not mask FP exceptions. And then they have an SEH handler that converts FP exceptions to `EMathError` exceptions. I always assumed C++ Builder did things the same way as Delphi does. Is that not the case?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Seems not. At least, catching `EMathError` or `...` does not prevent the standard "pow: OVERFLOW error" messagebox from appearing (__trying and __excepting do not help too). Documentation on `_matherr` do not mention EMathError at all, `_matherr` works as expected in debug (and under MSVC), that is why I think `_matherr` should be used.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't regard what MSVC does as having much bearing on what C++ Builder does. What 8087 control word is in use in your app? Does it differ in debug and release build?

Comment: `Get8087CW` returns 0x1372 in both cases though I have no idea of exact documentation on the bits. The only link I found interprets them as [cweAllowDenormals,                                         cweAllowUnderflow, cweAllowInexactPrecision], icAffine,     pcExtended, rcNearestOrEven
and with less limited words $133F and $027f my program still generates error messages on overflows.

Comment: That's a number I expect from Delphi experience. Sadly it looks like my Delphi expertise is not relevant or transferable here so I cannot help.

Comment: Have you tried switching between the dynamic RTL and the static RTL? (under linker options)

Comment: @DavidDean Eureka! The release build used the dynamic RTL in opposite to the debug build (if I'm understanding correctly, it is needed in order the release to use custom high-performance memory allocator for multithreaded simulation). Could you point me to explanation why dynamic RTL does not use user-defined `_matherr`?

Comment: I don't know why, but I did find this: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=70787

Comment: @DavidDean Thank you. I should have found it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to bug in the dynamic RTL which I use in the release build ([description](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=70787)). The bug was not fixed in the version of IDE I use, so the only working solution is to upgrade to a higher version. Nevertheless, having a clear explanation helps a lot.